# i am trying to upload and store files in multiple collections in Screen Flow but its not assigning ContentdocumentLink in Assignment

Tags: visual-workflow, contentdocumentlink, screen-flow, fileupload, collection

I am working on Screen Flow.
and i want to upload multiple files and also to store multiple file in related Record Id.
as i am doing with content document link i need to assign and add single content document link to multiple content document link..
but its not working like that .
Pls provide Soln for this..

[image: Assignment - Add Records into a Collection]